# xts object: mean over a specific month

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I've the following xts object.

```
x <- sample (19:22, 121, replace=T)
time <- seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"), length=121, by="months")

2001-02-01   21
2001-03-01   19
2001-04-01   22
2001-05-01   19
2001-06-01   19
2001-07-01   20
...
...
...
2009-11-01   21
2009-12-01   20
```

And I want to write a function or a code, that returns the monthly specific mean.
(the mean over all Januarys , mean over all Februarys and so on)

Is there a way to do it with a xts function like apply.monthly ?

At the end my Goal is to write a function, that Centers every monthly data point with its monthly specific mean

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to have something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)

#sample data    
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"), length=121, by="months"),
                 value = sample(19:22, 121, replace=T))

final_df <- df %>%
  group_by(months(date)) %>%
  summarize(value_mean = mean(value))
final_df
```

**Output is:**

```
   `months(date)` value_mean
 1          April   20.60000
 2         August   20.80000
 3       December   20.50000
 4       February   20.10000
 5        January   20.72727
 6           July   20.60000
 7           June   19.80000
 8          March   20.30000
 9            May   20.60000
10       November   20.80000
11        October   21.00000
12      September   20.40000
```